# MercurialEclipse on Windows 7 64bit: doesn't install "Windows Binaries for Mercurial"

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, mercurial, 64-bit

set up my machine at work (WXP 32bit) and MercurialEclipse in Eclipse Helios from market place worked without problems.

At home I did the same procedure but on W7Pro 64bit. MercurialEclipse itself got installed, but it errored out upon Workspace restart that the `hg` command was not found; and it's true, there was none installed.

Comparing the plugin configurations within both Eclipse installations I discovered that W7Pro 64bit misses the *Windows Binaries for Mercurial* plugin. Is that architecture dependent? Is there a way to fix this?

**Update:**

I verified with multiple installations: MercurialEclipse requires an external binary to properly work. I was confused because through testing on my first installation I also installed the *Windows Binaries for Mercurial* "somehow". On my second machine I didn't and I also hadn't installed MercurialHg.

By default MercurialEclipse simple requires `hg` in its configuration which implicitly assumes the binary must be available in the path somewhere. The *Windows Binaries for Mercurial* works a bit different, it installs a private copy of `hg.exe` inside the `eclipse/` folder somewhere and sets the absolute path in the MercurialEclipse configuration. Both ways work equally (ignoring differences which could be arise due version differences), since either installation would use your `mercurial.ini` from your home directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to pick up a copy of the hg (Mercurial) binaries from [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download).

Comment: Does this mean I need an external download for the 64bit, but not for the 32bit version of Windows?

Comment: If it's not there, then one can only assume yes. Probably just a packaging oversight.

Comment: Just my two cents. I was having problems with the built in MercurialEclipse binary due to version differences, so I pointed it to my TortoiseHg binary. Now Eclipse uses the same Mercurial binary as my shell an command line, and all is well.

Comment: In MercurialEclipse below 2.0, the binary hg.exe was packaged with the plugin update itself. [An option allowing you to check/uncheck the Installation of the binary was present]. They have removed this in 2.0 and I think the binary needs to be downloaded and then the preferences need to be changed in Windows-->Preferences-->Team--.Mercurial to the downloaded binary

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right; MercurialEclipse delegates control to the hg CLI. This has recently changed with 2.0, which uses [JavaHg](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/JavaHg) (which is a Java interface over the [Mercurial command server](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CommandServer)).

I have never used the [*Windows Binaries for Mercurial*](http://yoxos.eclipsesource.com/places/node/com.intland.hgbinary.win32.feature.group). My Windows setup comprises [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io) (choose the latest 32-bit or 64-bit release based on your supported platform), Eclipse (choose the latest 32-bit or 64-bit release based on your supported platform) and [MercurialEclipse](http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg.wiki/update_site/stable) (I have version 1.9.4.201203270141; I am yet to try 2.0.0, which was [released](https://plus.google.com/107778312851443989902/posts/V1eQykMvp6b) a few hours ago)